# Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-mipsel/Packages' in Release file

Tags: linux, debian, software-installation

I am currently running debian 8 jessie as my linux distro, and have been following this link to install HHVM https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/installation/linux the first two lines I have successfully carried out, however when I try to do a sudo apt-get update I get this error:

> W: Failed to fetch http://dl.hhvm.com/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease 
>   Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-mipsel/Packages' in Release
>   file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

Here is the whole trace:

```
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [63.1 kB]
Ign http://ftp.uk.debian.org jessie InRelease
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease
Ign http://deb.flowworld.com flowsdk InRelease
Get:2 http://dl.hhvm.com jessie InRelease [2,106 B]
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
Ign http://deb.flowworld.com flowsdk Release.gpg
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org jessie Release
Hit http://deb.flowworld.com flowsdk Release
Ign http://deb.flowworld.com flowsdk/main mipsel Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://deb.flowworld.com flowsdk/main mipsel Packages
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org jessie-updates/main Sources
Get:3 http://ftp.uk.debian.org jessie-updates/main mipsel Packages/DiffIndex [3472 B]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources [134 kB]
Get:5 http://ftp.uk.debian.org jessie-updates/main Translation-en/DiffIndex [1,20 B]
Ign http://deb.flowworld.com flowsdk/main Translation-en_GB
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org jessie/main Sources
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org jessie/main mipsel Packages
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org jessie/main Translation-en
Ign http://deb.flowworld.com flowsdk/main Translation-en
Get:6 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main mipsel Packages [237 kB]
Get:7 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en [132 kB]
Fetched 573 kB in 31s (18.1 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.hhvm.com/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease  Unable to ind expected entry 'main/binary-mipsel/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sourceslist entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones use instead.
```

here is my sources.list file:

```
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```

and here is the file running the command `echo deb http://dl.hhvm.com/debian jessie main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hhvm.list`

```
deb http://dl.hhvm.com/debian jessie main
```

Answer (score 1):

The HHVM repository you're using only provides binaries for `amd64` and `i386`, not `mipsel`.

Comment: Does that mean I have no other choice but to build from source?  or is there a way around this?

Comment: You could always ask the HHVM to provide `mipsel` binaries, but I doubt they'd be all that interested. Realistically you'll likely need to build from source.